# Omeka-s and Nginx - loop install

Tags: php, nginx, omeka

I have a machine with latest PHP and MySQL. I need to use Nginx. I managed to serve Omeka using this recipe:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/omeka/

When I go to my address I am presented with the ‘Install Omeka S - Create the first user’ page. When I fill it in and I submit, the response is the same page with an empty form, i.e. I’m stuck in a loop. The POST response in the browser console gives me a 404-not found error.

I feel I’m very close, can anyone shed some light on this? I feel that Omeka should not support Apache exclusively. Is this a Omeka-s issue? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what the issue is. The Nginx recipe I linked in my question is valid for Omeka, not Omeka-s. For Omeka-s one has to remove the /install and also edit the /admin location. This is the working configuration:

```
server {
        server_name omeka.domain.tld;
        root /var/www/omeka;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location /admin {
                try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

**Update**

I've pushed this recipe to Nginx wiki:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/omeka-s/